# Oracle DB read next unlocked row

Tags: sql, oracle, locking, oracle12c

I have following query running at three different instance of my application all trying to read row from a table one by one as a queue.

```
SELECT * FROM order_request_status ors WHERE ors.status = 'new' and ROWNUM <= 1 order by ors.id asc for update skip locked
```

now the issue is if the row is locked by one application instance i want my second application instance to read the next unlocked row by the query. but it is not working by this - for update skip locked.

Please suggest how i can implement a queue like feature using oracle db.

Answer (score 0):

The `SKIP LOCKED` processing happens after rows are returned by the query. Your predicate stops after reading just one record due to `ROWNUM<=1`, so if the record it finds has already been locked by another session, your query skips it and stops finding more records.

If you only want to process one record at a time, just fetch one record from the cursor instead of using `ROWNUM` to limit it.

Comment: how do i fetch just one record from cursor? i am using rownum to limit it so i can fetch the first record entered in the system by ordering id in ascending order.

Comment: `fetch cur into r` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#GUID-9DEED64C-A87E-4EAD-97DA-ABDD3FDF172C